# MYSQL error in trigger How to resolve?

Tags: mysql

MYSQL:

```
DELIMITER $$create TRIGGER `unit` beforeinsert ON `cart` FOR each row 
BEGIN
IF(EXISTS 
  ( 
         SELECT 1 
         FROM   `cart` 
         WHERE  `USER` = new.USER 
         AND    `item` = new.item)) THEN 
  UPDATE `cart` 
  SET    `unit` = new.unit, 
         `quantity` = new.quantity 
  WHERE  `USER` = new.USER 
  AND    `item` = new.item;ENDIF;
END 
$$ delimiter ;
```

Error:

```
Can't update table 'cart' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

When I am trying to insert data if already exist then it displaying error. I want to update data if the item is already in cart. How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

You can't UPDATE inside of the INSERT trigger instead of performing the INSERT. You either need to check for the record ahead of the insert in your code or perhaps look into using the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement:

```
INSERT INTO t1 (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;
```